# Automatic splitting into separate comments during conversion from answer

Tags: feature-request

Case in point: [this question on Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/26762/1543). The user pebox11 is unregistered, and so ended up with a duplicate account. Wanting to ask for more information from the accepted answer, he, not being able to post a comment, posted it as an answer.

As a moderator I converted that answer into a comment, and merged his accounts. But in doing so I noticed that the conversion 'mangles' answers over the character limit for comments.

**Suggestion**: is it possible to amend the software such that when moderators initiate the conversion of an answer to comment, it either

1. counts the number of characters and automatically breaks the comment (possibly at word boundaries) into pieces of less than maximum length, or
2. detects would-be over-long comments and allows the moderator some sort of manual intervention in splitting it up?